# Get object of selected slider - JQUERY UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using JqueryUI range slider which has multiple handles. How can I get the jQuery object of the handle when I start to slide?

Example : http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

I tried ..

```
$('#slider-range').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 10,
    max: 180,
    values: [ this.startDefaultVal, this.endDefaultVal ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) { }
});

$('#slider-range').on( "slidestart", function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(ui);   // get the slide object which is being dragged
});
$('#slider-range').on( "slidestop", function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(ui); // get the slide object which is being dragged
});
```

UI is a complete slider object but on start and stop I want to know which of the two sliders I'm actually dragging ?

Comment: The sliders are in in an array defined by ui.values with [0] being the first and [1] being the second. See this example - http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Comment: But i want the jquery element which is being dragged and not the values

Comment: Use ui.handle[0] and ui.handle[1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ui.handle` should give you the dragged handle

```
$('#slider-range').on( "slidestart", function( event, ui ) {
         console.log('s',ui.handle);   // get the slide object which is being dragged
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZpupJfgKGBdfUUyGrto2?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide).

```
ui
Type: Object

   handle
   Type: jQuery
   The jQuery object representing the handle being moved.
```

So you should be able to use ui.handle to get a regular jQuery object and read its id/class/...

```
$('#slider-range').on( "slidestop", function( event, ui ) {
    ui.handle // the slide jQuery object
});
```

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss Thanks for the edit, thought that the link to the docs was enough. This way it's even clearer.

Comment: Yes, this particular one is not as intuitive as a lot of others in the UI library.